# Minimize KL-divergence $D(p\|q)$ when $q$ is Gaussian

Tags: probability-theory, entropy

Consider $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are two pdfs of $X$, where $q(x)$ is a Gaussian distribution with the following form

$$q(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_q^2}} \exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma_q^2}\right).$$

Additionally, the variance of $x$ under pdf $p(x)$ is given (constrained), say $\sigma_p^2$, where $\sigma_p \neq \sigma_q$. Note that $p$ can be any pdf which is Lebesgue integrable.

Then which distribution $p(x)$ can minimize the KL-divergence $D(p\|q)$? The KL-divergence is defined as follows.

$$D(p\|q) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty p(x) \log\frac{p(x)}{q(x)} \, dx.$$

Thanks!

Note: If there is no variance constraint of $p(x)$, the answer is simply $p = q$ (a.e.). But this question is based on $\sigma_p \neq \sigma_q$. How to find the minimizer $p(x)$? Thanks a lot!

Comment: It seems that a logarithm is missing in your definition of KL-divergence?

Comment: @CaveJohnson Thanks very much for pointing out the typo :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint.** The optimal distribution is still Gaussian. In this case, the optimal Gaussian parameter is easily calculated. We show this by Lagrange multipliers:
$$D^*(p\|q)=\int p(x)\log\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}dx-\lambda_1\left(\int x^2p(x) dx-\mu_p^2-\sigma_p^2\right)\\-\lambda_2\left(\int xp(x)dx-\mu_p\right)-\lambda_3\left(\int p(x)dx-1\right)$$
By calculus of variation we get
$$
\log\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}+1-\lambda_1x^2-\lambda_2x-\lambda_3=0
$$
From which we may conclude $p(x)=q(x)e^{\lambda_1x^2+\lambda_2x+\lambda_3-1}$, hence a Gaussian.

Comment: write $p(x)dx$ as $dp(x)$ and then take derivative wrt $p(x)$.

Comment: @expiTTp1z0 Thanks very much for your help :-)

Comment: @CaveJohnson Thanks very much for your answer. I can just derive $\int \left[\log \frac{p(x)}{q(x)} + 1 - \lambda_1 x^2 - \lambda_2 x - \lambda_3\right] dx= 0$. Could you show me how to get the second equation? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Ryan It's a standard technique in calculus of variations. Take an arbitrary function $\phi$ and consider function $p_\alpha=p+\alpha\phi$.  Since $D(p_\alpha\|q)$ attains its extremum at $p$, i.e. when $\alpha=0$, Fermat's principle yields $\partial D(p_\alpha\|q)/\partial \alpha\big|_{\alpha = 0}=0$. This means $$\int \phi\left[\log \frac{p(x)}{q(x)} + 1 - \lambda_1 x^2 - \lambda_2 x - \lambda_3\right]=0$$ holds for arbitraty $\phi$, hence $\left[\log \frac{p(x)}{q(x)} + 1 - \lambda_1 x^2 - \lambda_2 x - \lambda_3\right]=0$ everywhere.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanations. I got a mistake when I applying the calculus of variation. Sorry...

Comment: Sorry, it says I have to give the bounty to you after 22 hours.

Comment: I revised the result, and it seems to be a typo.

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{align}D(p||q) &= E_{p}\left(\log\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}\right) \\
&= E_{p}(\log p(x)) - E_{p}\left(\log q(x)\right)\\
&= E_{p}(\log p(x)) - E_{p}\left(\log\left(\frac{\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma_q^2}\right)}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma_q}\right)\right)\\
&= E_{p}(\log p(x)) + \log(\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma_q) + E_{p}\left(\frac{x^2}{2\sigma_q^2}\right)\\
&= E_{p}(\log p(x)) + \log(\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma_q) + \frac{\sigma_p^2 + \mu_p^2}{2\sigma_q^2}\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}D(p||q) \geq 0 &\iff E_{p}(\log p(x)) + \log(\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma_q) + \frac{\sigma_p^2 + \mu_p^2}{2\sigma_q^2} \geq 0\\
&\iff H(p) \leq \log(\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma_q) + \frac{\sigma_p^2 + \mu_p^2}{2\sigma_q^2} = \log\left(\sqrt{2\pi e^{(\sigma_p^2 + \mu_p^2)/\sigma_q^2}}\sigma_q\right)\end{align}$$

$$D(p||q) = 0 \iff H(p) = \log\left(\sqrt{2\pi e^{(\sigma_p^2 + \mu_p^2)/\sigma_q^2}}\sigma_q\right)$$

Any distribution $p(x)$ with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma_p^2$, which has an entropy of $\log\left(\sqrt{2\pi e^{(\sigma_p^2 + \mu_p^2)/\sigma_q^2}}\sigma_q\right)$, will make $D(p||q) = 0$.

If one would like to minimize the KL-divergence and maximize the entropy of the distribution $p(x)$, then the $p(x)$ should be chosen to be a gaussian distribution with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma_p^2$.

**Edit**: I think the answer by @CaveJohnson is more appropriate than mine. However, I will keep my answer here for review later.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. [+1] Sorry, my question is not stated very clearly. I mean $\sigma_p$ is a given number (e.g., $\sigma_p = 1 + \sigma_q$), where $\sigma_p \neq \sigma_q$. I have already changed the description :-) Thanks!

Comment: Then you cannot minimize $D(p||q)$ since it will be a fixed quantity.

Comment: Is $D(p||q)$ fixed for all probability measures?

Comment: Once you fix your distributions $p$ and $q$ with all parameters of $p$ and $q$ known, then $D(p||q)$ will be a fixed number.

Comment: This wiki link will help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence#Definition

Comment: Thanks :-) The variance is fixed, but the distribution is not. I also guess the minimizer is Gaussian, but I don't know how to prove it...

Comment: Ohh. You meant that. Now, I understand. I will edit my answer then.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. My statement is not very clear. So sorry about that...

Comment: Thanks for your re-edited answer. There is assumption that $D(p||q)$ can be $0$, but it actually holds only for $p = q$, a.e. But still, thanks very much for spending your precious time with me. I really appreciate your answer and time :-)

Comment: Hi@DhruvKohli-expiTTp1z0 May I ask why $E_p(x^2)=\sigma_p^2 + \mu_p^2$?

Comment: $Var(x) = E(x^2)-E(x)^2$